# MSBuild 15 Tools Version not accepted

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, build-tools, build-server

I have installed the MSBuild (15.4.0) tools for Visual Studio 2017 on a build server.  To do this I used the link entitled "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017" from [Visual Studio Downloads](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/)

The path to the MSBuild.exe is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin

I have added this path to the Environment Variable 'path'.

I have a powershell script with the following as the body for the build task:

> msbuild '..\MyApplication.sln' /t:Build /tv:15.0
>   /p:GenerateBuildInfoConfigFile=false /p:Configuration=Release
>   /p:RunCodeAnalysis=True /p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0

But, when this is executed (all handled by TeamCity) I find the following in the LOG:

> MSBUILD : error MSB1040: ToolsVersion is not valid. The tools version
>   "15.0" is unrecognized. Available tools versions are "2.0", "3.5",
>   "4.0".

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/what-s-new-in-msbuild-15-0) suggests 15.0 should be correct.

**EDIT**
From the 2017 documentation on [What's New in MSBuild 15](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/what-s-new-in-msbuild-15-0) it states:

> MSBuildToolsVersion for this version of the tools is 15.0. The
>   assembly version is 15.1.0.0.

However, the 2017 documentation [MSBuild Command Line Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference) states:

> For MSBuild **4.5**, you can specify the following values for version:
>   2.0, 3.5, and 4.0. If you specify 4.0, the VisualStudioVersion build property specifies which sub-toolset to use. For more information, see
>   the Sub-toolsets section of Toolset (ToolsVersion).

So I'm a bit confused by the nomenclature: MSBuild 15 or MSBuild 4.5...?

Comment: PATH, the destroyer of good intentions.  Type "where msbuild.exe" and you'll probably see the wrong one listed first.

Comment: @Hans: C:\Users\Me>where msbuild.exe
 **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\
MSBuild.exe**

Comment: How about run the build command line from CMD directly? I have set that path on my side, and build a Visual Studio 2017 blank project successfully. You can try to create a blank project with Visual Studio 2017, then build on build server with above method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a fix. It was the path that was incorrect.

The solution was to change the powershell line above to:

```
$msbuild = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe'
    & msbuild '..\MyApplication.sln' /t:Build /m /p:GenerateBuildInfoConfigFile=false /p:Configuration=Release /p:RunCodeAnalysis=True /p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0
```